# Someone wants to answer my question, please reopen it

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I asked this question:

[Getting the error: "! Argument of \MT@res@a has an extra }."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298931/5640)

a while ago. Now someone has an answer, but the question is closed. They's just asked for help reopening it so they can reply. Can the kind readers of meta oblige us?

Answer (score 2):

The question has been reopened.

Btw. there are many comments on the question, perhaps some are obsolete today and could be cleaned? If yes and if you would flag those you cannot remove yourself, we can help cleaning.